# Add Sublime Text 2 to the right click context menu in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext2

Title pretty much sums my question. I want to open a folder in sublime text by right clicking the folder and clicking on "open folder in sublime text" context menu. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: For Ubuntu 21.04 and similar - https://github.com/atutorme/subl-nautilus. Uses the python3-nautilus package to add a context menu entry. Adapted from `code-nautilus`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you followed guide on:

http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/

You simply need to add a `%f` to your Exec line in `sublime.desktop` like:

```
Exec=sublime %f
```

Comment: %f or %F didn't work for me, I still don't get the program listed

Comment: Works fine; I edited my launcher (right click on desktop icon > properties > launcher, add %f at the end of the 'command' line) and all of a sudden it's in my context/right click menu

Comment: your link doesn't work. This is why you should add more info instead of just pasting links in SO answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have managed to get Right click context menu for Sublime Text 3:
Using [Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool](http://www.getdeb.net/install/nautilus-actions), either installed through Ubuntu software center with this link or through [ubuntuupdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/precise/apps/getdeb/nautilus-actions)

This will allow you to create right click context menus and actions to your liking.

I have created such an extension:
[Nautilus-Actions_XML_Schema](http://blog.ndroidians.com/?p=767)
OR
[Nautilus-Actions_Schema](http://blog.ndroidians.com/?p=765)

For further information check out: [blog.ndroidians.com](http://blog.ndroidians.com/open-with-sublime-text-3-context-menu-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-with-nautilus-actions/)

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> open with other application -> show all applications -> open with sublime text

Comment: sublime text 2 is not there in the list of applications

Comment: It doesn't appear when you select the  "show all applications" ?

Comment: Hrishi, yeah that works however it'd be nice to have it on the first level of the menu like the Open menu command

Comment: I choose `Open With` -> `Other Application` -> `Show other applications` (there is no "Show _all_ applications"), and Sublime Edit is not there. I'm quite sure I installed it manually, ie not with apt-get. Perhaps it must be installed with apt-get to appear in the list?

Answer (score 0):

This guide worked form me on Ubuntu and Mint. http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have copied the sublime `.desktop` file into the `/usr/share/applications/` directory. That should work resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To open a folder in sublime from nemo by right clicking in the pane for that directory, go into the folder **"usr/share/nemo/actions"** as sudo and create the file **"subl.nemo_action"** and put the following contents into it:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Open folder in Sublime Text
Comment=Open current folder in Sublime Text
Icon-Name=subl
Selection=any
Extensions=any
EscapeSpaces=true
Exec=/bin/sh -c "cd %P && subl ."
Dependencies=subl;
```

I found this solution [HERE](https://gist.github.com/justin-harper/9e24576880bedf27480ca177d0e22457), but had to change "subl3" to "subl" for my case, and had to find where to locate the file.